# Bubbling Events from UserControl using MVVM in WPF..?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, user-controls

First of all, I want to let everyone know that I'm very new to the MVVM concept, and have looked pretty extensively for some explanation of what I want to do, but to no avail.

In the program I'm working on, I have a UserControl with a few buttons on it, which need to control the navigation of the main window. I have 3 different "pages" I want to be able to switch between in my main window. Instead of pages, I decided (for whatever reason, correct me if this is not the best approach) to use a UserControl for each page, and switch the visibility to the correct one. I need the data to persist while switching, so I don't believe that creating new instances of the Usercontrols will work.

My question is: How can I bubble the events from my "NavBarView" to the main window in a way that will allow me to switch the visibility, but in a MVVM way? I know I may be completely going about this the wrong way, and I'm happy to take any suggestions on a better way of achieving this navigation.

I have to use WPF, so WinForms is not an option. Too much transparency and custom controls for WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the "NavBar" part of the main window if possible and use that to control the sub controls in the forms.  I would be careful nesting User Controls.  If you can avoid it I would  (key indication is are you going to reuse it somewhere else).  I took over a project a while back that had a main window with 3 separate highly coupled user controls that had to all work together and it was a nightmare.  The only way I could get it to work somewhat safely was to have them all set their data context to the same view model.  If I had to do it from scratch - would have taken a completely different approach with a single view.

Comment: I sort of had the same idea last night after some messing around with it. I was thinking of using a Frame that binded to a CurrentPage property. My questin is, how to I make the data persist during view changes? And, can't I use data from one view in another view? Wouldn't they need to share a viewmodel?

Comment: Yes you would need to set the data context for the views to the same view model.  You can then use multiple ways to determine what is displayed.  Think about how a wizard is used - you can use templates in your view that are triggered to show based on a setting on the view model - so it's automatic.

Comment: So, I change the SelectedPage property of my MainViewModel, which will in turn notify and automatically change which page is displayed in a frame?

Comment: yes - as long as you set it up in your xaml on what to display.  You will need to use templated bindings for this.

Comment: I have navigation working perfectly now, but there is a problem. Since I'm using a datatemplate to show the correct view, I can't figure out how to do data binding from view to viewmodel. 

Also, is there a standard way of calling events on one viewmodel from another? When I create the secound VM, can I pass a reference to the "parent" vm, then call methods that way?